# How does the cgi.FieldStorage class work with file uploads?

Tags: python, file-upload

The entire question is pretty much in the title.

The only documentation I can find on the class is the **very** sparing [cgi documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/cgi.html?highlight=cgi#using-the-cgi-module) and it doesn't mention in the least how the class receives the file, how it's stored, what functions it supports etc.

I'm very interested in where the uploaded file is stored. Clearly it's not in memory, since [Bottle](http://bottlepy.org/docs/0.10/tutorial.html?highlight=file%20upload#post-form-data-and-file-uploads) mentions the `FileStorage.read()` function is dangerous on large files. If it's placed on the disk, I would like to move it to a permanent location without having to read through it in Python copy it bit by bit to a new location.

But I have no clue where to begin due to the poor documentation of the class. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

A little late, but looking into this myself:

It all comes down to the 'make_file' method in cgi.py:

```
def make_file(self, binary=None):
    import tempfile
    return tempfile.TemporaryFile("w+b")
```

The tempfile docs ( http://docs.python.org/2/library/tempfile.html ) identify that the file is created in a default directory chosen from a platform-dependent list, but that the user can control the directory location by setting one of the environment variables: TMPDIR, TEMP or TMP.

Please also note from the documentation:

> Under Unix, the directory entry for the file is removed immediately
>   after the file is created. Other platforms do not support this; your
>   code should not rely on a temporary file created using this function
>   having or not having a visible name in the file system.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this could help:

http://epydoc.sourceforge.net/stdlib/cgi.FieldStorage-class.html

`cgi.FieldStorage()` has

- a "filename",
- a "value" - the file itself,
- a "file" and
- a "type"

And something else... you could read in the doc.

Here is my code:

```
f_sd=open(tempfilesd,'r+b')
newdata_sd = cgi.FieldStorage()
newdata_sd.filename='sdfile.jpg'
newdata_sd.name='file'
newdata_sd.file=f_sd
form.vars.file = newdata_sd
```

Answer (score -1):

The `FieldStorage.file` attribute is actually not a file but a `cStringIO` object, which is described as a *memory file* on the docs: http://docs.python.org/library/stringio.html

Maybe this can help you a bit.

Comment: If that is the case, how come I can upload a 4GB disk image and the Python process stays on 15M RAM usage all throughout? And again, the bottle docs warn against using `FileStorage.read` since it'll "read the entire file into memory". That wouldn't be a problem if the file was already in memory, I would figure.

Comment: Any response to my comment?

Comment: I tried reading it from [the source](http://hg.python.org/releasing/2.7.3/file/7bb96963d067/Lib/cgi.py#l328) , and apparently you're right! It seems to use StringIO just for buffering. The comments say that you should override some of the classes methods if you want to move the temporary file, but I don't know who you can make the WSGI framework use a different `cgi` implementation.